# How to set properties in content of ArrayController

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

While debugging when I try to access content

```
this.get('this.content').objectAt(0).selected_group
true
```

but When I try to set selected_group it gives me following error

```
this.get('this.content').objectAt(0).selected_group = false;
Error: assertion failed: Must use Ember.set() to access this property
```

again when I try to set selected_group using setter method it gives following error

```
Ember.set(this.get('this.content').objectAt(0).selected_group, false)
TypeError: Object #<error> has no method 'indexOf'
```

this.get('content').objectAt(0) looks like following

```
Object {id: "GRP1", divisions: Array[6]}
__ember1364353119575_meta: Meta
divisions: Array[6]
0: Object
budget: Object
current_month_proj: Object
division_name: "North Florida"
facilities: Array[8]
id: "DIV1"
last_year: Object
prev_month: Object
prior_three_months: Object
__proto__: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
5: Object
length: 6
__proto__: Array[0]
get group_name: function () {
id: "GRP1"
set group_name: function () {
__proto__: Object
```

What is the correct way of setting/adding attributes to content (which is an array of obj) of ArrayController ?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the correct path.  You just need to fix a few things.

Instead of `this.get('this.content')`, use `this.get('content')`.

Also, here's how to use Ember.set:

```
this.get('content').objectAt(0).set('selected_group', false);
```

Since an ArrayController is a proxy, you can directly access its array without `content`:

```
this.objectAt(0).set('selected_group', false);
```

Also you can use Ember's special array property `firstObject`:

```
this.set('firstObject.selected_group', false);
```

Comment: When I try to set the selected_group in the above mentioned way it say TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'set' P.S. I have updated the question to show the object also

Comment: also this object is a json response its not created like Ember.Object.create

Comment: is it like we should have as a standard that while dealing with ember concepts we shud always have ember object instead of normal object? what is the best strategy to follow?

Comment: Correct.  If you want to use Ember.js binding, you need to use Ember.js Objects.  Arrays however automatically become Ember.js Enumerable Objects so you don't need to worry about them.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found out a solution to my problem, instead of having vanilla json object we should always have ember object , we can wrap our json objects with ember wrapper, this would provide methods like set and get

Answer (score 0):

or you use serializers. anyway, as long as your object doesn't have an attribute called "selected_group" (and, going by your sample object, this seems to be the case), you won't be able to set it either way.